# Help solving Modified 1 dimensional heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

$u_t(t,x)=u_{xx}(t,x)-u(t,x)$ and $x\in(0,1), t>0$

with boundary and initial conditions

$u(t,0)=0, u(t,1)=e-e^{-1}, u(0,x)=f(x)$.

I tried using auxiliary function $v(t,x)=u(t,x)-(e-e^{-1})x$ but failed to hold the first equation.

Without auxiliary function;

Let $u(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$ then by the first equation,

$T'X=TX''-TX$,

${T'\over T}={X'' \over X}-1:=-\lambda$,

Let $\mu := \lambda-1 $, then $X''-\mu X=0$,

$ X = c_1{e}^{\sqrt{\mu}x}+c_2{e}^{-\sqrt{\mu}x}$

But with boundary condition $u(t,1)=T(t)X(1)=e-e^{-1}$, I have no idea how to proceed.

Help me, Thank you!

Comment: One of the boundary conditions looks strange: $u(t,x)=0$ ?

Comment: Sorry i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Observe that the function 
$$ w(x) = e^x - e^{-x} $$
satisfies 
$$ w''(x) = e^x - e^{-x} = w(x) $$
or that
$$ w''(x) - w(x) = 0 $$

Furthermore, $w(0) = 0$ and $w(1) = e - e^{-1}$.

So if you decompose $u(t,x) = v(t,x) + w(x)$ you have that $v(t,x)$ solves

$$ v_t = v_{xx} - v $$

with boundary data

$$ v(t,0) = v(t,1) = 0, \qquad v(0,x) = f(x) - w(x) $$

For $v$ you can solve the equation using, e.g., Fourier series.

Comment: Really helped. Thanks!